# I'm getting a bad request error when I try to submit a form inside of a modal

Tags: python-3.x, forms, modal-dialog

I'm trying to allow users to submit their gematria calculations to a text file so I can check them by hand before submitting them to the database; therefore I've place a simple form inside of a modal with an input type="submit" but I keep getting a 400 bad request error and I can't figure out why this isn't working.

I'm using Python3.6 server side with flask and I'm NOT using bootstrap with the html.

**Server side:**

```
if request.form["action"] == "Send":
    Name = request.form["name"]
    Email = request.form["mail"]
    GematriaNum = request.form["gematria"]
    Source = request.form["source"]
    Calc = request.form["calc"]
    LIT = request.form["transliteration"]
    LANGY = request.form["translation"]
    NEWSL = request.form["newsletter"]
    BODYOF = Name + Email + GematriaNum + Source + Calc + LIT + LANGY + NEWSL

    with open("submiss.txt", "w") as submiss:
        submiss.write(BODYOF)

    return render_template("index.html")
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

**Webpage code:**

```
    <!-- ...it's part of a nav bar. -->
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <li><a id="myBtn">Submit your Calculations to the Database!</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <form action="." method="POST"><span>
        Name:<br>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="name" cols="25" rows="1" maxlength="25"></textarea><br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="mail" cols="25" rows="1" maxlength="25"></textarea><br>
        Gematria Number:<br>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="gematria" cols="25" rows="1" maxlength="25"></textarea><br>
        Source Text [i.e. Exodus 2:12]:<br>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="source" cols="25" rows="1" maxlength="25"></textarea><br>
        Calculation in Hebrew, Greek or English:<br>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="calc" cols="50" rows="1" maxlength="100"></textarea><br>
        Transliteration (if applicable):<br>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="transliteration" cols="50" rows="1" maxlength="100"></textarea><br>
        Meaning and Usage:<br>
        <textarea style="resize:none" name="translation" cols="50" rows="1" maxlength="100"></textarea><br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="newsletter" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Sign up for our newsletter?<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"></span>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
    <br>
    Thanks!
</div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

You can see the site live [here](http://shematria.pythonanywhere.com/).

I hope you can help.

Comment: can you give me the full error code? what flask provides when access the information at front end??

Comment: It says "Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Comment: There's nothing in the error log.

Comment: i am sorry, i can't find anything just by seeing the code itself, do you have this project on github?

Comment: I'm on Pythonanywhere so I can share links from there:

For the flask app:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/Shematria/shares/afd90a457fbb41d69013aac52f3ab877/

For the html:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/Shematria/shares/308d4f4996d345b6a27f81f81c73f9ee/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  Much appreciated.  :-)

Comment: i think i got the problem your flask server is not running can you confirm you had used app.run()??? also you are coding in pythonwhere or in some ide?

Comment: Pythonanywhere is hosting the site which is up and working.  If the flask server wasn't working wouldn't that mean the site wouldn't be showing?  It seems to be working fine apart from the modal issue:  http://shematria.pythonanywhere.com/)

Pythonanywhere says we shouldn't use app.run because it's configured through the wsgi file:  

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/

Comment: i am not familiar with pythonanywhere, and i am keep figuring how this hosting works, meanwhile i will give you a head start, when you logged in(pythonanywhere) right hand side you will see 'web' navbar which will take you where you can access your website, so in this page if you scroll down you will see a header which named as logs, there is that error log which i meant earlier you can check that and see if it solved your problem

Comment: Yes, the error log isn't showing any errors, although posting the form still produces a 400 bad request event.  It's really weird because post works elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 3):

Missing `name="action"` on the submit button input field and no handled case for the null value of newsletter checkbox is causing the bad request.

Because action is unset, you never get to

```
if request.form["action"] == "Send":
```

I used Chrome in developer mode (**F12**) to find the post formdata. When I noticed action and newsletter were not in the post data, I edited the HTML live and was able to make a successful post.

Goodluck on your continued learning B

Comment: Thanks Jayme!  That totally works!  I'm afraid I can't vote up answer because my reputation isn't high enough but this is the right answer.  :-)